# Program crashed when i search using combobox autocomplete

Tags: c#, combobox, bigdata, large-data

I'm trying to search in array variable have big data using combobox autocomplete.

And this is my work:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Thread thread1;

    long test1 = 0;
    string randName;
    String[] ComboboxValue = new String[20001];

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thread1 = new Thread(add_combo_1);
        thread1.Start();
    }

    private static Random random = new Random();
    public static string RandomString(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }

    private void add_combo_1()
    {
        while (test1++ < 20000)
        {
            randName = RandomString(1000);
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () {
               //comboBox1.Items.Add(randName.ToString());
               ComboboxValue[test1] = randName.ToString();
                comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(ComboboxValue[test1]);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This what i use setting of combobox:

[image]

I think crash happened when i searching and the program still loading data to array.

So any one have a solution?

Comment: What exception is thrown and in which line?

Comment: Also, why not disable the box until you actually have the data loaded?

Comment: I'm just making this random to test big data load. So when you type the suggestion lines must appear.

Comment: @Trey I need to search even if the data still load

Comment: You're going to need some doevents or sleeps within the loop.  My thought is why not populate a datasource and then set the combobox to pull from it?  Using a combobox that is being actively populated is risky conflict wise.  What if you did a lock around "comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add" ? Also, please share what the exception is, it will really help with a solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to let the program finish going through the while loop that you set unless you insert a    `break;` inside with or without a IF statement inside the loop

Comment: Thank you for inform me this,, I make progress bar to see the load data before start work.

Comment: No, a break will just exit the loop.  Obada says he needs it to continue loading.

Comment: @Trey putting another loop around it will work because its a while loop not a for loop. A for loop will start counting all over again and  Obada will have to perform a loop within a loop a if statement that breaks the inner loop and then programmatically search the array. otherwise it is impossible to get something that's already running to start running without stopping the first operation